# Read HttpListenerRequest.InputStream multiple times

Tags: c#, .net, http, httplistener, httplistenerrequest

I am currently working with the HttpListener class. I have created a little API with it and i now want to log the payload of each request (if there is one).

Unfortunately, I encountered a problem while doing this. Once I read the `Request.InputStream` for writing it into my log, I am unable to reset the `Position` property, as well as getting the `Length`. I assume the input stream is not buffered and therefore this operations are not available (although I don't quite understand why `Length` is unavailable).

The input stream might be needed at a later time, so I tried copying it into a MemoryStream via `.CopyTo`, but this wont work either. Of course there would be the option of reading it once and handing it over to the next methods who might need it, but I would prefer keeping the original InputStream property.

Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: What didn't work with the `MemoryStream`? You can't reset the position on the `InputStream` because the underlying stream is a read-once HTTP connection to a web server

Comment: It still gets consumed, just like as I would read it normally. My deserialization method fails as it cannot find anything when reading the stream. Okay, this confirms my theory there is no buffering and it's gone once read.

Comment: I think what @Rhumborl was suggesting was that you should read the `InputStream` to the `MemoryStream` and then use it for both your logging and deserialization (since it can seek). Of course, if you're dealing with large input then `MemoryStream` itself could be problematic... but one bridge at a time :)

Comment: That's my current solution, and as I don't want to use reflection for hacking around with the original stream, this might be the solution. But there is now indeed the problem of dealing with large payloads, as @Brad mentioned.